# Recording IP camera RTSP stream to a .mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, ip-camera, rtsp, fps

I was wondering if anybody can help me figure out what I am doing wrong in the following scenario.
So my goal is to record an RTSP stream from an IP camera to a .mp4 file. I have 4 x Vstarcam-C7824 cameras. All of them work fine if I just open the stream like `rtsp://user:pass@ipaddress/udp/av0_0` and I can see the video and hear the audio. My problem is recording streams from 2 of those cameras to a mp4 file. The other 2 works fine. So I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -i rtsp://user:pass@ipaddress/udp/av0_0 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a mp2 -y -f segment -segment_time 5 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 ./video-%M.%S.mp4 -loglevel verbose
```

This keeps making 5 second long videos. The problem is that this works fine only for 2 of my cameras. I can view the recordings and hear the audio as well. The other 2 cameras I can only hear the audio when playing back the recording. These cameras are all the same model. Maybe it has something to do with the stream that camera provides. Codecs used by the cameras are :

```
Video - Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)

Audio - Codec: PCM ALAW (alaw)
```

Below is the output of ffmpeg command using the camera, recorded file of which can be played:

```
    C:\Users\dellpc\Desktop\records>ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.7/udp/av0_0 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a mp2 -y -f segment -segment_time 5 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 ./video-%M.%S.mp4 -loglevel verbose
ffmpeg version 2021-08-18-git-dbe40478e2-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57.  4.101 / 57.  4.101
  libavcodec     59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavformat    59.  4.101 / 59.  4.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[tcp @ 0000023d4d80e940] Starting connection attempt to 10.10.10.7 port 554
[tcp @ 0000023d4d80e940] Successfully connected to 10.10.10.7 port 554
[rtsp @ 0000023d4d80e280] SDP:
v=0
o=VSTC 3838537728 3838537728 IN IP4 10.10.10.7
s=streamed by the VSTARCAM RTSP server
e=NONE
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:1024
a=control:track0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f;sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AH52oFAFum4CAgKAAAAMAIAAAAwHwgA==,aO48gA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
b=AS:64
a=control:track1
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000/1


[rtsp @ 0000023d4d80e280] setting jitter buffer size to 500
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000023d4d813440] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuvj420p
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.7/udp/av0_0':
  Metadata:
    title           : streamed by the VSTARCAM RTSP server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, left), 1280x720, 7.50 fps, 18.92 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 0000023d4f7fe100] tb:1/8000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:8000 chlayout:0x4
[format_out_0_1 @ 0000023d4d8be340] auto-inserting filter 'auto_aresample_0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'format_out_0_1'
[auto_aresample_0 @ 0000023d4fae3a40] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:8000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:16000Hz
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Selected stream id:0 type:video
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Opening './video-30.02.mp4' for writing
Output #0, segment, to './video-%M.%S.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : streamed by the VSTARCAM RTSP server
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.101
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive, left), 1280x720 (0x0), q=2-31, 7.50 fps, 18.92 tbr, 15360 tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, delay 481, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.5.100 mp2
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 6062, current: 0; changing to 6063. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:0 pts_time:0 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:1152 pts_time:0.072 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 6063, current: 1690; changing to 6064. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 6064, current: 3195; changing to 6065. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 6065, current: 4132; changing to 6066. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 6066, current: 5683; changing to 6067. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:2304 pts_time:0.144 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1823, current: 415; changing to 1824. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:2305 pts_time:0.144063 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1824, current: 1567; changing to 1825. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:2306 pts_time:0.144125 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:3200 pts_time:0.2 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:4352 pts_time:0.272 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:5504 pts_time:0.344 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:6656 pts_time:0.416 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:6524 pts_time:0.42474 frame:0
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.02.mp4' count:0 ended=1.74x
[AVIOContext @ 0000023d4d875380] Statistics: 2 seeks, 5 writeouts
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Opening './video-30.05.mp4' for writing
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.05.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:80933 pts_time:5.26908 frame:60
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.05.mp4' count:1 ended=1.28x
[AVIOContext @ 0000023d4d8a2e40] Statistics: 2 seeks, 5 writeouts
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] Opening './video-30.11.mp4' for writing
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.11.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:162310 pts_time:10.5671 frame:120
[segment @ 0000023d4d8a6d40] segment:'./video-30.11.mp4' count:2 ended=1.23x
[AVIOContext @ 0000023d4faeb180] Statistics: 2 seeks, 4 writeouts
frame=  145 fps= 14 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:12.65 bitrate=N/A speed=1.22x
video:558kB audio:240kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.7/udp/av0_0):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 145 packets read (570989 bytes);
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 77 packets read (98560 bytes); 77 frames decoded (98560 samples);
  Total: 222 packets (669549 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (./video-%M.%S.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 145 packets muxed (570989 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 171 frames encoded (196992 samples); 171 packets muxed (246240 bytes);
  Total: 316 packets (817229 bytes) muxed
Exiting normally, received signal 2.

C:\Users\dellpc\Desktop\records>
```

**Now below here is the ffmpeg command output using the camera recorded file of which doesn't show video only audio is heard.**

```
    C:\Users\dellpc\Desktop\records>ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.14/udp/av0_0 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a mp2 -y -f segment -segment_time 5 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 ./video-%M.%S.mp4 -loglevel verbose
ffmpeg version 2021-08-18-git-dbe40478e2-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57.  4.101 / 57.  4.101
  libavcodec     59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavformat    59.  4.101 / 59.  4.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[tcp @ 000002257d8ae940] Starting connection attempt to 10.10.10.14 port 554
[tcp @ 000002257d8ae940] Successfully connected to 10.10.10.14 port 554
[rtsp @ 000002257d8ae280] SDP:
v=0
o=VSTC 3838538240 3838538240 IN IP4 10.10.10.14
s=streamed by the VSTARCAM RTSP server
e=NONE
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:1536
a=control:track0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=00f004;sprop-parameter-sets=6QDwBE/LCAAAH0gAB1TgIAAAAAA=,AAAAAA==
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 8
b=AS:64
a=control:track1
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000/1


[rtsp @ 000002257d8ae280] setting jitter buffer size to 500
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000002257d8b3440] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 000002257d8ae280] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000002257d8ae280] RTP: missed 56 packets
[rtsp @ 000002257d8ae280] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 000002257d8ae280] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 000002257d8b3440] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.14/udp/av0_0':
  Metadata:
    title           : streamed by the VSTARCAM RTSP server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(progressive, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088), 30 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph_0_in_0_1 @ 000002257d96eec0] tb:1/8000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:8000 chlayout:0x4
[format_out_0_1 @ 000002257d96cf80] auto-inserting filter 'auto_aresample_0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'format_out_0_1'
[auto_aresample_0 @ 000002257d96d080] ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:8000Hz -> ch:1 chl:mono fmt:s16 r:16000Hz
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] Selected stream id:0 type:video
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] Opening './video-38.03.mp4' for writing
Output #0, segment, to './video-%M.%S.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : streamed by the VSTARCAM RTSP server
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.101
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(progressive, left), 1920x1080 (0x0), q=2-31, 30 fps, 25 tbr, 15360 tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, delay 481, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.5.100 mp2
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:0 pts_time:0 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:1152 pts_time:0.072 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:2304 pts_time:0.144 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:3456 pts_time:0.216 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:4608 pts_time:0.288 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:5760 pts_time:0.36 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:6912 pts_time:0.432 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:8064 pts_time:0.504 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:9216 pts_time:0.576 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:10368 pts_time:0.648 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:11520 pts_time:0.72 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:12672 pts_time:0.792 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:13824 pts_time:0.864 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:14976 pts_time:0.936 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:16128 pts_time:1.008 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:17280 pts_time:1.08 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:18432 pts_time:1.152 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:19584 pts_time:1.224 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:20736 pts_time:1.296 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:21888 pts_time:1.368 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:23040 pts_time:1.44 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:24192 pts_time:1.512 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:25344 pts_time:1.584 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:26496 pts_time:1.656 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:27648 pts_time:1.728 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:28800 pts_time:1.8 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:29952 pts_time:1.872 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:31104 pts_time:1.944 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:32256 pts_time:2.016 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:33408 pts_time:2.088 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:34560 pts_time:2.16 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:35712 pts_time:2.232 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:36864 pts_time:2.304 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:38016 pts_time:2.376 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:39168 pts_time:2.448 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:40320 pts_time:2.52 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:41472 pts_time:2.592 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:42624 pts_time:2.664 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:43776 pts_time:2.736 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:44928 pts_time:2.808 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:46080 pts_time:2.88 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:47232 pts_time:2.952 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:48384 pts_time:3.024 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:49536 pts_time:3.096 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:50688 pts_time:3.168 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:51840 pts_time:3.24 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:52992 pts_time:3.312 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:54144 pts_time:3.384 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:55296 pts_time:3.456 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:56448 pts_time:3.528 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:57600 pts_time:3.6 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:58752 pts_time:3.672 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:59904 pts_time:3.744 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:61056 pts_time:3.816 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:62208 pts_time:3.888 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:1 pts:63360 pts_time:3.96 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:61902 pts_time:4.03008 frame:0
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.03.mp4' count:0 ended=2.41x
[AVIOContext @ 000002257f69b0c0] Statistics: 2 seeks, 6 writeouts
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] Opening './video-38.07.mp4' for writing
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.07.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:123342 pts_time:8.03008 frame:100
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.07.mp4' count:1 ended=1.66x
[AVIOContext @ 000002257f7e3bc0] Statistics: 2 seeks, 5 writeouts
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] Opening './video-38.11.mp4' for writing
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.11.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:184782 pts_time:12.0301 frame:200
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.11.mp4' count:2 ended=1.45x
[AVIOContext @ 000002257f7e3500] Statistics: 2 seeks, 7 writeouts
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] Opening './video-38.15.mp4' for writing
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.15.mp4' starts with packet stream:0 pts:246222 pts_time:16.0301 frame:300
[segment @ 000002257f7e4d40] segment:'./video-38.15.mp4' count:3 ended=1.35x
[AVIOContext @ 000002257f7e33c0] Statistics: 2 seeks, 6 writeouts
frame=  397 fps= 27 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:19.84 bitrate=N/A speed=1.35x
video:1950kB audio:374kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (rtsp://user:pass@10.10.10.14/udp/av0_0):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 496 packets read (2278651 bytes);
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 120 packets read (153600 bytes); 120 frames decoded (153600 samples);
  Total: 616 packets (2432251 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (./video-%M.%S.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 397 packets muxed (1997267 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 266 frames encoded (306432 samples); 266 packets muxed (383040 bytes);
  Total: 663 packets (2380307 bytes) muxed
Exiting normally, received signal 2.

C:\Users\dellpc\Desktop\records>
```

The only difference that I managed to notice myself is the FPS and resolution difference between the streams. Does it have anything to do with that perhaps?

Any input is appreciated!

Teymur

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and cured it by making sure it was using a TCP connection, by adding `-rtsp_transport tcp` before `-i`, so:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:pass@ipaddress/udp/av0_0 -map 0 ...
```